# Number the dataframes within the list (i.e., create a column with an individual number for each dataframe)

Tags: r, list, dataframe, lapply

I need to be able to distinguish the dataframes within the large list with an individual number, so that I can `group_by`based on that number after binding the dataframes (in my case it is impossible to just work with a list without binding).

Example:

```
df1 <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 3, nrow = 8))
colnames(df1) <- c("a", "b")
df1$a <- seq(1, 8)
df1$b <- seq(4, 11)
df1
df2 <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 3, nrow = 8))
colnames(df2) <- c("a", "b")
df2$a <- seq(2, 9)
df2$b <- seq(5, 12) 
df2
list <- as.list.data.frame(c(df1, df2))
bind <- do.call("rbind", list)
```

Expected result:

```
bind
```

```
   a  b number
 1 1  4      1
 2 2  5      1
 3 3  6      1
 4 4  7      1
 5 5  8      1
 6 6  9      1
 7 7 10      1
 8 8 11      1
 9 2  5      2
10 3  6      2
11 4  7      2
12 5  8      2
13 6  9      2
14 7 10      2
15 8 11      2
16 9 12      2
```

Comment: Note that in the example, you are creating a `NA` column, which is not needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `bind_rows` and specify the `.id` to create a grouping index variable

```
library(tidyverse)
bind_rows(df1[-3], df2[-3], .id = "number")
```

---

Or with `base R` using `Map`

```
do.call(rbind, Map(cbind, list(df1[-3], df2[-3]), number = 1:2))
```

---

If there are multiple object names with the same pattern identifier 'df1', 'df2', ..., 'df247', use `mget` to get the value of the string identifier in a `list` and then use `bind_rows`

```
bind_rows(mget(paste0("df", 1:247)), .id = "number")
```

Comment: How would I use it with lapply and a large list (247 elements)?

Comment: @aazh Did you created the 247 objects 'df1', df2', df3', ,df247 in the global env?

Comment: I have list of 247 objects of my real data in the global environment, I just used two dataframes for a reproducible example

Comment: @aazh In that case, just do `bind_rows(lst1, .id = "number")` assuming the column names are the same in all the datasets in the `list`